# How to use Observers with socket callbacks?

Tags: java, android, observable, rx-java2

I`m an android developer who is interested in testing new technologies.
Know, I want to use the Architecture Components for improvement of my projects.

I want to list the articles from the server and show them in the recyclerView.
It should be noted that I have used the WebSocket to communicate with the server.

My routine is as follows:

First, I called loadArticles method from viewModel class:

```
BlogViewModel = ViewModelProvders.of(this).get(BlogViewModel.class);
viewModel.loadArticles();
```

Below the body of the BlogViewModel:

```
public class BlogViewModel extends ViewModel {

private BlogRepository repository;
private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

public ObservableField<Boolean> isLoading = new ObservableField<>();
public MutableLiveData<List<Article>> articles = new MutableLiveData<>();


public BlogViewModel() {
    this.repository = new BlogRepository();
}

public void loadArticles() {
    isLoading.set(true);

    compositeDisposable.add(repository
            .getArticles()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<Article>>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Article> data) {
                    articles.setValue(data);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    // FIXME: 3/31/2019
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    isLoading.set(false);
                }
            }));
}

@Override
protected void onCleared() {
    super.onCleared();

    if (!compositeDisposable.isDisposed()) {
        compositeDisposable.dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Also, BlogRepository class is defined as follows:

```
public class BlogRepository {

private BlogRemoteDataSource remoteDataSource = BlogRemoteDataSource.getInstance();

public Observable<List<Article>> getArticles() {
    if (Util.isConnect()) {
        return remoteDataSource.getArticles();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

And BlogRemoteDataSource class is defined as follow:

```
public class BlogRemoteDataSource {

private Application app = (Application) Application.getInstance();
private List<Article> articles;

public static BlogRemoteDataSource getInstance() {
    return new BlogRemoteDataSource();
}

public Observable<List<Article>> getArticles() {
    JSONObject objData = new JSONObject();
    try {
        objData.put("itemID", "");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    app.getSocket().observe(app.getOwner(), socket -> socket.event(Api.EVENT_GET_ARTICLE)
            .data(objData)
            .setCallbacks(new SocketCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONObject data) {
                    try {
                        articles = Article.parse(data.getJSONArray(Constant.PARAM_BODY));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int code, String message) {
                }
            }).send());

    return Observable.just(articles);
    }
}
```

My problem is when I return the Observable.just(articles) as output. After executing this line, the onNext method in the class is BlogViewModel once triggered, but when the list of articles is taken from the server and the value, onNext method is not triggered.

Please guide me how to tell ViewModel, the data is ready?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thsnks Tamir Abutbul!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use observeForever instead of observe only because observeForever() is not tied to any LifecycleOwner. so use it like below:

> First remove your BlogRepository class and update BlogViewModel as
>   below:

```
public class BlogViewModel extends ViewModel {

private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
private BlogRemoteDataSource remoteDataSource = BlogRemoteDataSource.getInstance();
public ObservableField<Boolean> isLoading = new ObservableField<>();

public BlogViewModel() {
    this.repository = new BlogRepository();
}

public void loadArticles() {
    isLoading.set(true);
    remoteDataSource.getArticles();
}

@Override
protected void onCleared() {
    super.onCleared();
    if (!compositeDisposable.isDisposed()) {
        compositeDisposable.dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Then update BlogRemoteDataSource as below:

```
public class BlogRemoteDataSource {

private Application app = (Application) Application.getInstance();
public MutableLiveData<List<Article>> articles = new MutableLiveData<>();

public static BlogRemoteDataSource getInstance() {
    return new BlogRemoteDataSource();
}

public void getArticles() {
    JSONObject objData = new JSONObject();
    try {
        objData.put("itemID", "");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    app.getSocket().observeForever(app.getOwner(), socket -> socket.event(Api.EVENT_GET_ARTICLE)
            .data(objData)
            .setCallbacks(new SocketCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONObject data) {
                    try {
                        List<Article> newArticeList = Article.parse(data.getJSONArray(Constant.PARAM_BODY));
                        articles.postValue(newArticeList);
                        articles.notifyObserver();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int code, String message) {
                }
            }).send());
    }
}
```

Hope it helps now!! :)

Comment: Thanks my friend, your solution dismissed me from LifecycleOwner, But it still does not work.